# last_scan_date and timestamp in Python

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime

looking for an advise. Everyday I scan the SalesForce to find new opportunities and update the data accordingly. I am looking for a library or method that will store the last_scan_day and create a timestamp afterwards. So that the next day when the code scans for new opportunities it knows what the last_scan_day was - only checks the data that is Date >  last_scan_day and updates the timestamp with a new date. And so on. It is a very high level of what I am trying to do, but if anyone can direct me to the right python methods, that would be awesome.

Currently, this works for me in php, but I need to translate it to Python.

```
    $last_run_date = file_get_contents("./last_scan_date.txt");
    $last_run_date = str_replace("\n","",$last_run_date);

    $t = getDatetimeNow();
    $t = substr($t,0,19)."Z";
    file_put_contents("./last_scan_date.txt",$t);
```

Comment: Hi Chique_Code, I think all your answers would be in module [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html). Can you show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

from datetime import date, timedelta

yesterday = date.today() + timedelta(days=-1)